# How do I make a fixed size grid-pane in JavaFX Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to make a centered grid pane in the JavaFX scene builder which stays a fixed size. I'm having a hard time doing this myself. Anything I can do?

[image]

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

[image]

Comment: If you click on the row/column indicators and open the "Layout" pane on the right you should be able to set constraints.

Comment: As Slaw pointed out, you can create row/column constraints by clicking on the "headers" for the `GridPane`. I would warn against setting exact sizes, though, and opt for using `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` for the `Pref Width/Height` and `USE_PREF_SIZE` for the minimums. That creates rows/columns that resize automatically to fit their contents.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks a lot Slaw & Zephyr

Answer (score 0):

You can use stackpane as parent of your gridpane